# How update information on page without it reload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I want to get different lists of films by using API.
I have a list of films, list of items in a header like "Popular Upcoming Top rated", using react-router-dom and when click on some of these items there load list of films.

Problem in next:
When I come on the page of films using items from header in component of FilmList I replace some part of link to getting right link for getting films like:

```
    componentDidMount(){
        let filmApi =`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${this.props.filmType}?api_key=6f7c9fe2b5229b4b0b6dbe66fed3ef18&language=en-US&page=1`;
        // this.props.filmType i get when go on page of film (Popular->popular, Top rated-> top_rated

        this.props.getListFilms(filmApi); // here I send this ready link to fetch it in redux
    }
```

It works but just the first time, because of using the react router dom when I click on next item like from popular to top-rated page didn't reload and link stay for the previous list of film. How can I do that when I change the list of films it correctly works? Maybe I need to use await async?

Comment: please describe more what you actually want to do .

Comment: You have to update `state` for updating data. Can you show us the change of `state` you are making?

Comment: --Problem in next: When I come on the page of films using items from header in component of FilmList I replace some part of link to getting right link for get films like:--

Explaun a bit more about this

Comment: I use this  Link on header                                                                                                
 ```  <Link to="/top_rated">
             top rated
       </Link>```   and go on page /top_rated then using this component I render ListFilm ```
export default function ChooseListFilm() {
    let {name} = useParams();
  return (
    <div className="films">
        <ListFilms  filmType={name}/>
    </div>
  );
}
``` In filmType lying "top_rated" which I use in Film list that I described in post @costal oktopus @ Al Amin  @ Vyas Arpit

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you call the api, push the response in your state, then check this.state is equal to nextState or not. If not, write a function and do what you want.

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState, nextContext) {
  const {data: preData}= this.state
  const {data: nextData} = nextState
  if(preData !== nextData) console.log("data has changed")
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, your problem is "you can not update the same page with different values". ComponentDidMount function does your fecthing process at the beginning of the page loading time but when you try to change it doesn't render.So you need to use ComponentDidUpdate function with adding if condition there. Compare previous data and currently fetched data and use your getListFilms  function again. I think it will work.

Comment: Yes, you are right! But it work when I switch between home page and one of Items with film.But when i try to switch between popular and top Rated for example it didn't work. Mybe i done something wrong?  ```      ComponentDidUpdate(prevProps){
        if (this.props.filmType !== prevProps.filmType) {
            let filmApi = this.props.filmApiTemplate.replace("{film_type}",this.props.filmType);
            this.props.getListFilms(filmApi);
            console.log(filmApi)
        }
    }``` Sorry for my English

Comment: if you use a different component ,maybe you can not pass this props properly or you can not update state variables properly. I think you need to check them. Can you share your code? it is hard to solve this problem without see it.

Comment: I wrote my code in codePen but I don't know if you  will understand.[link](https://codepen.io/Orest97/pen/NWGLJjd?editors=0010)

Comment: Your componentDidUpdate function doesn’t look like wrong but I think you cannot save in state and pass the data properly